# why does a node.js process suddenly die on osx with no explanation in any log file?

Tags: macos, node.js, coffeescript, kill, pid

90% of the time I always get a stack trace.  But sometimes the process just quits and I have no idea why.  Anyway to print the stack trace always?  Or find more information in dmesg or something?

Comment: Sounds like Node itself crashes. It depends on which platform you use (Windows, Mac, Linux) how you could debug that.

Comment: on osx and it's happening more and more.  Node is chugging along just fine and then boom, process dies with no explanation.  any idea how to find more information?

Comment: Check `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` to see if there are crash logs related to your Node processes. The logs might provide a clue why Node crashes.

Comment: i got excited there for a second, lots of files in there with the info I'm used to from when I did iphone app development.  But they are all from osx apps I run on this mac, nothing from node.

Comment: That sounds like Node is either killed by another process, or it just exits cleanly. Without a log, the only way I can think of for tracing these issues without actually resorting to a debugger is to enable lots of tracing info (see `node --v8-options`) and hope to find what's causing the problem :(

Answer (score 11):

okay finally found a way to find the error:

```
node --trace app.js
```

it outputs every function call and I can see the stacktrace right before it exits with:

```
startup.processKillAndExit.process.exit
```

And my stacktrace points to:

```js
redis.get('bar', (err, data) -> JSON.parse(value).foo)
```

`JSON.parse(value)` comes back `null` so `.foo` throws:

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null]
```

and for some reason the `TypeError` inside a redis callback is swallowed and causes node to exit without printing the error.

Comment: Ahah.. a way to debug, thanks..  I have a similar issue it seems